# How to get a complete list of all installed software via Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to figure how to view the version numbers of all installed software in Powershell on Windows 10. I dug up an [example](https://techdirectarchive.com/2020/12/22/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-installed-program-using-powershell-in-windows-10/) but when I compare the generated list to what's in *Control Panel > Uninstall a Program*, it seems incomplete. For instance, Google Chrome is missing from the query output. Any idea why? I have very little experience with Powershell so maybe something obvious?

`Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product" |FT`

Chrome is certainly installed but doesn't show up in the PS output:
[image]

Comment: Win32_Product will provide information on Windows Installer managed applications. Vendors aren't required to use Windows Installer, they may have their own installer. Additionally, many applications don't have an installer. Just copy the file(s). There is a reason there are companies that have products that audit and inventory applications.

Comment: Which products in particular are you thinking about? If you know of a solution which actually works as-advertised I'd love to try it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Get-InstalledApps {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [string]$NameRegex = ''
    )
    
    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName) {
        $keys = '','\Wow6432Node'
        foreach ($key in $keys) {
            try {
                $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $comp)
                $apps = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames()
            } catch {
                continue
            }

            foreach ($app in $apps) {
                $program = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$app")
                $name = $program.GetValue('DisplayName')
                if ($name -and $name -match $NameRegex) {
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        ComputerName = $comp
                        DisplayName = $name
                        DisplayVersion = $program.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                        Publisher = $program.GetValue('Publisher')
                        InstallDate = $program.GetValue('InstallDate')
                        UninstallString = $program.GetValue('UninstallString')
                        Bits = $(if ($key -eq '\Wow6432Node') {'64'} else {'32'})
                        Path = $program.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use: `Get-InstalledApps -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME`

Comment: This captures Chrome, as well as Adobe Acrobat. Thank you!